# How can I check if device encryption is enabled on a particular volume in Windows 10?

Tags: winapi, encryption, drive

How can I check if device encryption is enabled on a particular volume in Windows 10, preferably without requiring admin?

Device encryption is not bitlocker, which i already know how to check for. Device encryption is its own thing.

I'm not going to enable it; I just need to check if it's there or not.

Comment: What makes you think that every encrypting drive in the world bothers to tell the OS that it is doing encryption?

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's not _exactly_ that the drive is encrypted that I want to check for. I want to check that the OS has it set up so that you can't see the unencrypted data by booting from CD.

Comment: Are you asking about NTFS encryption or encryption in general?

Comment: @IInspectable: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-encryption-in-windows-10-ad5dcf4b-dbe0-2331-228f-7925c2a3012d

Comment: You can use `GetVolumeInformation()` to check if a volume supports filesystem-level encryption or not, and then `FileEncryptionStatus()` or `GetFileAttributes()` to query if a given file/directory is encrypted or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Encrypting file system is again something else entirely.